# Joining two tables - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two datasets: A and B

Dataset A:

```
indiv_id      January     
1000068000004   1   
1000068000011   1   
1000068000012   1
```

Dataset B:

```
indiv_id       March     
1000068000003   1   
1000068000011   1   
1000068000015   1
```

Desired Result:

```
Indiv_id      January    March    
1000068000003  null       1    
1000068000004   1        null  
1000068000011   1         1   
1000068000012   1        null    
1000068000015  null       1
```

How do I join the tables so that I have all of the `Indiv_IDs` from BOTH lists and their values in the column that is distinct to their particular dataset?

Thanks

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve!

Comment: yeah otherwise we don't know what you want when you have the same indiv_ID in both tables - a single combined line or two separate lines?

Comment: I've updated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `full join`:

```
select indiv_id, a.january, b.march
from a full join
     b
     using (indiv_id);
```

The `using` clause makes this particularly convenient because you don't need to worry about any `coalesce()`s in the `select`.

Comment: That `USING` tidbit is a nice bonus.  I'd never realized that.

Answer (score 0):

You've got 3 cases to deal with: the ID is in both datasets, the ID is only in dataset A, or the ID is only in dataset B. You can't solve that with `select ... from dataset_A left join dataset_B ...` because you'll get the first two cases but not the third.

What you need is to define a view that gives you all the IDs across both datasets, then left join to each dataset:

```
with all_IDs as (select indiv_ID from dataset_A union select indiv_ID from dataset_B)
select indiv_ID, january, march
from all_IDs
left join dataset_A using (indiv_ID)
left join dataset_B using (indiv_ID)
```